# Make div dropdown field push div subdrop down

Tags: html, css

Given the codepen below: https://codepen.io/ricocode/pen/Expwbyy

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.field,
.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px 2%;
}

.message {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="field">
    First Name
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    Last Name
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    Email
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="field dropdown" onclick="myfunc">
      Department
    </div>
    <div class="field subdrop">
      Sub-dept
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="message">
    Message
  </div>
</div>
```

When sub-dept is not visible, the fields align nicely.
[image]

When sub-dept is toggled as a result of choosing an option for department, I want department to stay in its initial location and have sub-dept push content downward but instead, sub-dept pushes Department up and shifts Email down with it.
[image]

I want Email and Department stay in the original location but have Message shifted downwards. How to do so?

I've tried making the min-width bigger to account for this addition but I don't want to have the extra space pre-accounted for.

Comment: You could try adding `display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap` to your container - that will keep your email at the top, but seems to mess up the padding / margin so it's not quite aligned with your department.  Or you could add `vertical-align: top` to your field, but that also has a slight mis-alignment

Comment: Flexbox is my usual approach to these problems but I'm using hubspot forms and surprisingly I haven't been able to successfully add flex capabilities to them. This is aside the issue but hopefully this context means something to someone.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the css you can use @Jfar41? Grid would be a good solution for this imho

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to modify the code snippet for .dropdown-box

```
.dropdown-box {
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

thank you @pete user:1790982